# Batch Renaming Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Edited this question to try and clarify.

I'm trying to write a simple renamer script to change files in the current directory 'test1.txt, test2.txt, testcab.txt' etc, to 'edit1.txt edit2.txt editcab.txt' and so on.

I want the user to be able to select which part of the filename they want to change, and what they want to change it to using variables oldText & newText

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

read oldText
read newText

if [ -e "$oldText*.txt" ]
        then
                mv "$oldText*.txt" "$newText*.txt"
        else
                echo "Sorry, no existing file named" $oldText
fi
```

This works without the `*` if I type the full 'test1', but I'm trying to find a way to simple replace all the instances of 'test' in the filenames with 'edit'. Am I wrong for trying to achieve this with `if`? Should I be using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mv` line, the first variable needs a capital `v`.

```
mv $myVar1 $myVar2
```

**EDIT**

Your `test` statement has a `-a` which tests if the EXPRESSION is true.  It would be better to check for it's existence using a `-e` like this:

```
[ -e $myVar1 ]
```

See `man test`.

Comment: Damn it, I knew it was something like that. Thanks a bunch man!!